# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a page which can edit the filename, artist name and album name of the uploaded song. Currently the error states as

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\User] does not exist

web.php

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UploadController;
Route::post('/updatesongs/{id}', [UploadController::class,'update']);
```

UploadController.php

```
public function update(Request $request,User $id)
    {   
        $songname = $request->input('song_title');
        $songartist = $request->input('song_artist');
        $songalbum = $request->input('song_album');
        DB::update('update music_uploads set filename = ?, artistname = ?, albumname = ? where id =?', [$songname, $songartist, $songalbum,$id]);
        echo "Updated successfully <br>";
        echo '<a href="/ngsongs">Click here to return</a>';
    }
```

Solutions I've tried

1. `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
     protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';
```

uncommenting this line doesn't solve the problem

2. clean the cache `php artisan route:cache` doesn't work

Any other solutions or is my code wrong?

Comment: `User` model is not found in the current namespace, you need to `use` the correct namespace

Comment: Anytime you reference a Class in a file, like `User $user`, or `User::create()`, etc etc, you need to make sure that Class is available in the current Class, either implicitly if they share the same namespace, explicitly via the full namespace (`App\Models\User::create()`), or via an Import as shown in the answer below. There are plenty of questions on Stackoverflow with this same or similar error, with the same solution as below; please spend some time checking next time.

Comment: Also, you're type-hinting that `$id` is a `User`, but then use it in your query as an actual id.  This doesn't seem right...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should provide the namespace for the User model that you use as a parameter in your controller:

```
use App\Models\User

// .......

public function update(Request $request,User $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

we can create a controller Artisan command:

```
php artisan make:controller QuizzStatusController
```